# Ruby on rails: Stylesheets not working ExecJS::ProgramError

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Error page:
[image]

Here's the application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>YoutupediaBlog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I have searched for solutions for this problem the past two days. I have tried many things.

Most solutions says to change 'application' to 'default' in the stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag. Which it dose work and the page is loaded successfully, but!! Stylesheet is not loading. My page styling is not shown.

Here's my posts.scss file (which it's in the app/assets/stylesheets directory)

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: proxima-nova, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2A4550;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px;
}
```

I'm so depressed right now, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you missed `nodejs`, because i had some problems same as you.

You can try to do as following:

First, install `NodeJS` on your local machine (make sure the corresponding entry is added to the PATH)

Second, add `gem 'execjs'` to your `Gemfile`.

And run `bundle install`

Comment: Yeah, that solved it. I have never imagine the solution would be this easy.
Thank you so much!!

Comment: But, what about when I want to publish my website in the internet.
Do I need to install node.js in the server?

Comment: @AbbasAleid yes, you must install `nodejs` in server.