# stylesheet_link_tag together with Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like to set Bootstrap on Rails 5.1.5, following the tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout but the procedure with the Gemfile won't work.

After some readings, in particular here: [Installing Bootstrap 3 on Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371318/installing-bootstrap-3-on-rails-app)  I ended up downloading the css files and copying them directly in app/assets/stylesheets.

Now I get this error:

```
Invalid CSS after "...quire bootstrap": expected "{", was ""
```

linked to this line in application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

As I understand, this line is processed with the application.scss file that I have created in app/assets/stylesheets (where there was a file application.css). This file has only one line:

```
*= require bootstrap
```

After looking further in the docs, I have made a test with:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap" %>
```

and from there I get another error:

```
TypeError: Cet objet ne gère pas cette propriété ou cette méthode
```

which means 'this object doesn't deal with this method'.

Just another misconfiguration of my Rails installation or what ?

> Is it possible that a nodeJS installation solve the problem ? I've found a reply here [Ruby on rails: Stylesheets not working ExecJS::ProgramError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194685/ruby-on-rails-stylesheets-not-working-execjsprogramerror) which seems to have made it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually installing NodeJS can help a lot: this should be the very first thing to do for window users!

Comment: Don't forget to additionally place the bootstrap.js file and the bootstrap directory (with all the js files such as dropdown.js, transition.js, etc) in the app/assets/javascript directory